# Converting a graph to a biparte to find the maximal matching

Tags: graph-theory

Im trying to get the maximal matching via trial and error (for the matching problem) derived from the following graph:

[image]

But before I do this, I know I need to convert it into a biparte graph?

Ive constructed a biparte before by using independent sets, but here if i use {3,7,8} i get a very redundant biparte. Is there an algorithm for conversion?

I know this graph has a matching of `size 4 {{1,2},{5,9},{6,10},{11,12}}` but it is not maximal. The only way I can figure how the maximal can be found is by converting to a bipate, or is there another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you may be confusing the terms "maximal matching" and "maximum matching". By the Wikipedia definition, your current matching is a maximal matching. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)

Comment: The easiest way to split the vertices in two classes to make the graph bi-partite is to $2$ color the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

To partition your bipartite graph, just take any vertex, say 1, put it in A, and put all its adjacent neighbours 2 and 4 in B. You continue until all the vertices are partitioned into one of A or B, if you run into trouble it's not a bipartite graph.

Thus you will have: `A = {1, 5, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11}` and `B = {2, 4, 6, 9, 12}`. The maximum matching is size 5.

Now you find any matching, your current one is fine so let's use that. Mark the edges that are in that matching, `{1,2},{5,9},{6,10},{11,12}`.

Observe that there is an [alternating path](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~sankowski/lecture2.pdf), `5 - 9`, that starts and ends on vertices in the matching.

Furthermore we can augment this alternating path since 5 connects to free vertex 4 and 9 connects to free vertex 8.

We create the [augmented path](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~sankowski/lecture2.pdf) `4 - 5 - 9 - 8`, and reverse the matching status of each edge each edge in the augmented path. Thus the matching in the augmented path becomes `{{4,5},{8,9}}`.

Our matching is now size 5, and includes `{{1,2},{4,5},{6,10},{8,9},{11,12}}`. This is the maximum matching.

Comment: Why is {5,9} eliminated, as this was contained in the original set, is it because of the augmented path you have demonstrated? Thanks

Comment: In order to augment an alternating path, you have to be able to add vertices that are not in the matching to both ends of the alternating path. {5,9} is not the only possible alternating path you could have augmented. In fact, you could have taken the alternating path `1 - 2 - 5 - 9` and augmented it to get `4 - 1 - 2 - 5 - 9 - 8`, and then "inverted" the matchings in the augmented path so your final matching is `{{4,1},{2,5},{9,8},{6,10},{11,12}}`, also size 5.

Comment: In a bipartite graph with bipartition $(A,B)$, the maximum size of a matching is less than or equal to $|A|$. It need not be equal.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil For a connected bipartite graph, the maximum matching is equal to the minimum of (|A|,|B|). It's an implication of Koenig's theorem as both A and B are covers.

Comment: @Reila Lee: Take two copies of the path on three vertices, and add an edge joining the two vertices of degree two. This is connected and has three vertices in each colour class. But there is no matching of size three.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Oops you're absolutely right, I'll fix it.